# VideoView in Fullscreen

Tags: java, android

How do I get the VideoView to go Fullscreen in lanscape?

I've set the following in the manifest file for the activity.

android:screenOrientation="landscape"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">

Is there anything else I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `VideoView` to fill the screen using `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height`.

Note that the actual video will not fill the screen in most cases, because the aspect ratio of the video will not match the aspect ratio of the screen.

Comment: I've got the LinearLayout and the VideoView layout_width and layout_height both set to fill_parent. Video takes up about 60% of the width of the screen. Desire HD.

Comment: @Tsuma-Shifu: If the video takes up the height of the screen, then it is working as expected, based on the aspect ratio.

Comment: So I set the background of the activity to red so that I could see how much of it was taken up by the video view. Can clearly see that the video view is not spanning the whole activity. How do I get the VideoView to span the whole activity and maintain its ratio.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
   <VideoView android:id="@+id/myvideoview"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </VideoView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

the align's are needed

Answer (score 0):

By changing the configuration of layout you can stretch your video.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <VideoView android:id="@+id/videoViewRelative"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </VideoView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

To make the activity fullscreen you can change the theme as follows

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Or you can do it by adding the code below before `setContentView()` method in `onCreate()` in the activity (java) class.

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,  
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```