# Not displaying videoview in full screen

Tags: android, media-player, android-videoview

Everyone. I would like to videoview displays the video in full screen, I've tried using some commands, but they didn't work out. I need some help. I put below my code.

The video continues showing about 1/3 of screen! I'm a newbie!!!

Intro.JAVA

```
         public class Intro extends Activity {  
     public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
           getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
         requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
         setContentView(R.layout.intro);

         VideoView vid = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
         String uriPath = "android.resource://com.english/raw/videoenglish";
         Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);
         vid.setVideoURI(uri);
         vid.start();
         vid.requestFocus();

         vid.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

         public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent main = new Intent(Intro.this, IntentsDemoActivity.class);
                    Intro.this.startActivity(main);
                    Intro.this.finish();
            }

          });
         }
        }
```

INTRO.XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe it's the resolution of the video?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the actual video will not fill the screen a lot of the time, because the aspect ratio of the video does not match the aspect ratio of the screen itself.

I suspect that the VideoView itself is filling up the whole screen. Try with a different device or the emulator.

Here are some other questions for reference either way:

- [Reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701825/videoview-in-fullscreen)
- [Reference 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027216/video-view-is-not-full-screen-in-landscape-mode)